# Display a table in visualforce with non dynamic rows

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I need to create a table in a VF page, but I need to create it row by row (with a header and footer)

For now I have something like that :

```
<apex:pageBlockTable >
    <apex:column>
        <apex:facet name="header">Prestation</apex:facet>
        <apex:facet name="footer">Total prestation</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="row1"/>
        <apex:outputText value="row 2"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">BO</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="row 1"/>
        <apex:outputText value="row 2"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I have a table with 2 columns, and I want it to have also 2 rows. But with that I only got a table with 2 columns and 1 row...

Comment: have you looked into using [apex:dataTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm)?

Comment: You'll want to use apex:panelGrid.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, with apex:panelGrid is ther a way to add a header for the table and a footer ? So it looks like an apex:pageBlockTable ?

Comment: You can add a header and footer, but you'd have to work out the CSS yourself. If you want to have a pageBlockTable, you need to have two rows of data to have them appear in your columns correctly. It doesn't matter that they're not dynamic from your point of view, if you want multiple rows, you need a list.